# grep and awk parse line

Tags: awk, grep, logging

I have e a line that looks like:

```
Feb 21 1:05:14 host kernel: [112.33000] SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=90.90.90.90 PREC=0x40 TTL=51 ....
```

I would like to the a list of uniq IPs from `SRC=`

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will work, although you could probably simplify it further in a single awk script if you wanted:

```
awk  '{print $7}' <your file> | awk -F= '{print $2}' | sort -u
```

Comment: I'd write `awk '{split($7, a, /=/); print a[2]}' file | sort -u` to avoid calling awk twice

Comment: ... and there you go! (I have tremendous faith in awk :-) Thanks glenn.

Answer (score 2):

`grep -o 'SRC=\([^ ]\+\)' | cut -d= -f2 | sort -u`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat thefile | grep SRC= | sed -r 's/^.*SRC=([^ ]+).*$/\1/' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk script will do:

```
{a[$7]=1} 

END{for (i in a) print i}
```

Comment: that will emit the prefix `SRC=` for each line

Comment: @glenn I think that is OK. As the OP commented "Thanks everybody!" before I answered, so I think my answer was left unread. In any case, a substr(i,5) solves the problem, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the IP addresses in order without the "SRC=" string:

```
awk '{a[$7] = $7} END {asort(a); for (i in a) {split(a[i], b, "="); print b[2]}}' inputfile
```

Example output:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po "SRC=(.[^\s]*)" file | sed 's/SRC=//' | sort -u
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/SRC=(.[^\s]*)/)[0] if /SRC=/' file| sort -u
```