# Consolidate multiple similar lines in log with bash

Tags: bash, shell

Sometimes I would get errors such as the lines below in web server error log:

```
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18703#18703: *1148440 limiting requests, excess: 10.897 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18703#18703: *1148443 limiting requests, excess: 10.891 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18703#18703: *1148441 limiting requests, excess: 10.888 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18703#18703: *1148444 limiting requests, excess: 10.885 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18703#18703: *1148445 limiting requests, excess: 10.873 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18704#18704: *1148446 limiting requests, excess: 10.845 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18703#18703: *1148447 limiting requests, excess: 10.844 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18703#18703: *1148448 limiting requests, excess: 10.839 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/09/19 04:32:49 [error] 18703#18703: *1148449 limiting requests, excess: 10.836 by zone "flood", client: 10.20.30.40, server: domain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

I've a bash script that parses log files each day, but it just dumps all the lines into the report.

```
function error_log_errors {
  ERRORLOG_ERRORS=$(cat "${ERRORLOG}" | grep "${ERRORLOG_DATE}" | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$6))}')
}
```

How can I consolidate multiple of such similar lines into:

```
(20) 04:32 Limited requests (zone: flood) from IP address: 10.20.30.40, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: domain.com
```

The columns are:

- Number of times of occurrence
- Time it first started
- Event (corresponding entry in log: limiting requests, excess: 10.897 by zone "flood")
- IP address
- Request (corresponding entry in log: request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1")
- Host name

Thanks for any advice.

Note: Please note that the log file also contains other unrelated lines as well. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into logcheck?  It's a utility that monitors logs and emails you results.  I believe it condenses similar lines, if you set it up to do so.  Here's an overview: https://www.maketecheasier.com/logcheck-analyses-log-files-linux/

Comment: You could use 'uniq -c' to remove duplicates and get the number of times each of them is repeated, and the rest of fields are easily obtainable with awk and cut (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5068611/4530890). But I'm not going to write the entire script for you. If you are doing server stuff you probably already know your way around bash.

Comment: @Ocab19: Yes, I'm aware of uniq -c but it removes duplicate lines, while in my case, each line is different.

Comment: Well, you can use `sed` or something to get rid of the parts of the line you don't care about and then run the result through `uniq`.  I mean, `uniq` will also skip a given number of leading fields or characters, but in this case the bits you care about are all over the line. Honestly, I would use a dedicated off-the-shelf log-parsing tool for this.

Comment: @GooDoo, there's more to `uniq -c` than checking *whole* lines, comparisons can be between partial lines, using the `--skip-fields=N` and `--check-chars=N` options -- see `man uniq` for details.  For more complex lines, feed the log to `cut` to keep only the desired fields, then pipe its output to `uniq -c`.